# Why Line.Stroke.ToString() return 8 symbols hex code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, colors

I have class who convert string hex code to Brush object

```
public static class StringBrushConverter
{        
    public static Brush FromStringToBrushConvert(string hexCode)
    {
        var converter = new BrushConverter();
        return (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(hexCode);
    }
}
```

When I try to find Line with some color of stroke I can't find it.

```
foreach (System.Windows.Shapes.Line child in canvas.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Shapes.Line>())
{
    if (child.Stroke == StringBrushConverter.FromStringToBrushConvert("#d7d7d7"))
    {
        canvas.Children.Remove(child);
    }
}
```

Is not throw me exception is just can't find. When I add all brushes in list I find something when I don't know why is it make. The stroke is not #D7D7D7. Is #FFD7D7D7.

My questions is:

1. Why .Net is add FF before my hex code who I set like stroke in Line.
2. What is mean this two FF.
3. Can is change FF to be like B3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dealing with an ARGB entity here - 'alpha', 'red', 'green' and 'blue'. If you only specify 3 elements as you did in your code (`"#d7d7d7"`) the  converter implicitly adds an alpha channel of 255 (full strength).

When it is converted back to a string, it will include the 'ff' (=255) at the front of the ARGB value.

Answer (score 2):

The first two letter means opacity and of course you can change it.

Besides, your second piece of code is wrong because you're trying to compare to objects' reference instead of value. Try to use object.Equals().